# I need to extract string(that is coming from a list) from line

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I am trying to extract "strings" which are items of List. There are 200 lines from which I need to extract strings which are item(s) of a list, there are 54474 items in the said list, I am passing the line from which the items of the list are to extracted as sub-string if exists. I am passing both to the function as an argument as below:-

```
private static string FindMatchingSkill(string line, List<string> skillsfromMongoDB)
    {
        StringBuilder builtString = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in skillsfromMongoDB)
        {
                string temp = " " + item;
                builtString.Append(line.Substring(line.IndexOf(temp), temp.Length).Trim() + ", ");
        }
        return builtString.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I feel sorry for the applicants if this is how their resumes are being filtered. ;)

Comment: Could you please read [ask] and then read [mcve]? You should have provided us with sample input data (as valid C# code), working code, and the desired output. Currently your input doesn't look complete, and your code doesn't compile, and it doesn't appear to output what you're asking for (but I can't really tell because the explanation is unclear).

Comment: Don't use Exceptions for flow control. That's slow for a start. Calculate the index and then decide whether or not to use it using an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
var result = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
var searchInLines = new string[200]; // filled with resumes 
var dictionary = new string[50000]; // search dictionary

searchInLines.AsParallel()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(Environment.ProcessorCount * 2)
    .Select(searchInLine =>
        {
            result.Add(searchInLine, dictionary.Where(s => searchInLine.Contains(s)).ToArray());
            return string.Empty;
        })
    .ToList();
```

Produces dictionary with "Resume" to found dictionary items.

If you use inaccurate `string.Contains` then it will work quickly in 0.2 seconds

If you use RegEx like `Regex.IsMatch(searchInLine, $"\\b{s}\\b"))` (to find words), then it will work slowly in 30 seconds.

The choice is yours

Comment: string.Contains might give false positives, as I've explained in my answer. Perhaps a good approach would be to use string.Contains to get possible matches as fast as possible, and then filter them further to minimize the false positives.

Comment: @ZoharPeled It's OP choise for what to do next

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you want to do is not to substring the original string, instead, print out the item from the list.
Instead of:

```
Console.WriteLine(line.Substring(line.IndexOf(item), item.Length).Trim() + ", ");
```

use

```
Console.Write(item +", ");
```

But to do that, you need to get only the items that are actually in the string, so your loop should be something like this:

```
foreach (var item in data.Where(i => line.IndexOf(i) > -1)
```

That might leave you with some false positives, since if the line contains `javascript` and not `java`, you will get both.

So the next step is to identify what is a full world and what is not - now that might be a problem, since `dot net` is two words but it's just one item. Also, Items in the original string might be followed by chars other then white space - like a comma, a dot, semicolon etc'.
So instead of just using `IndexOf`, you need to also make sure the item you found is not a part of a larger item - and since your list items are not restricted to be a single word, that poses a real difficulty.

I would probably suggest something like this:

```
foreach (var item in data.Where(i => line.IndexOf(i) > -1 && !Char.IsLetter(line[line.IndexOf(i) + i.Length + 1])  && !Char.IsLetter(line[line.IndexOf(i) - 1]))
{
    Console.Write(item +", ");
}
```

Testing the char after the item to make sure it's not a letter. If it is, then it's a false positive. Please note that since your items might contain non-letters chars you might still get false positives - if you have both `dot net core` and `dot net` in the list, but the line only have `dot net core` you will get a false positive for `dot net`. However, this is an edge case that I think it's probably safe to ignore.

Comment: Tx @zohar peled plz see function it might give me some more idea to understand
private string FindMatchingSkill(string line, List<string> skillsfromMongoDB)
{
     StringBuilder builtString = new StringBuilder();  
     foreach (var item in skillsfromMongoDB)
     {
      try
       {
       string temp = " " + item;
       builtString.Append(line.Substring(line.IndexOf(temp), temp.Length).Trim() + ", ");
       }
       catch (Exception ee) {
       if (ee.Message.Contains("StartIndex cannot be less than zero."))
          continue;
        } return builtString.ToString();
 }

Comment: Please avoid pasting code into comments. Instead, edit your question with the code you want to ask about.

Comment: Might be better to use regex for matching word boundaries. (My first instinct would be to make the matching one single regex, but with 50k items I guess that would be a bit of a mess...)

Comment: Note that some skills may be names of programming languages or software packages ending on _numbers_, so `IsLetter` may not be advised. Also, this doesn't check the front boundary.

Comment: @Nyerguds Correct. I thoght about using a regualr expression but I think it's going to be too much overhead

Comment: @Nyerguds I've added a test for before the item. I think IsLetter should cover most cases but it can be changed to IsLetterOrDigit.

Answer (score -1):

The list of `data` being bigger is not good to be looped through. I would suggest to loop through the line as it is smaller. Considering there would always be space between words.

```
List<string> data = new List<string>() { "Delphi", "dot net", "java", "Oracle" }
String line = "Dheeraj has experience in dot net java programming Oracle javascript and Delphi";

foreach (var item in line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }))
{
    // If you use Contains here, it will use sorting and searching the keyword
    if(data.Contains(item))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code would never find `"dot net"`. It's also a bit unclear what the OP wants - your code does something different from theirs. I suspect neither is right.

Comment: @praty I have posted  whole function's code below the reply of Mr. Zohar Peled, the problem is if do so then I will have to split my string with "S++" or " " but by doing so that completely changes the output as in the list there are item in my list as "C# DotNet" and "C#" "Dot Net", so if I split my string then it will totally change the output and that will be of no use as I tried it before as you have suggested.